# Stop UIWebView from reloading

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

So I have a `UIWebView` and a very simple line of code in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
[bandcamp loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hatfilms.bandcamp.com"]]];
```

It works so that when I push a button, a new view loads and this is the code that is executed. Trouble is, when I then go to another view, and then go back to the webView ViewController, the webView reloads. When I play music in the webView, the music keeps playing but the webView reloads - like it's created another instance of itself.

How would I stop this from happening?